# jQuery dataTables sDom positioning

Tags: css, datatables, tabletools

Please refer to the following image:
[image: Figure No. 1]

I'm trying to move the tableTools buttons (Copy, Excel, CSV) down a little bit so that it looks like the buttons are at the same level as the Search Box... I've tried all kinds of sDom parameters without success.

Here's my current initialisation code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').dataTable({
                "bSort": false,
                "bPaginate": false,               
                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                "oTableTools": {
                    "sSwfPath": "../../Scripts/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
                    "aButtons": ["copy",
                                {
                                    "sExtends": "xls",
                                    "sButtonText": "Excel",
                                    "sFileName": "*.xls"
                                },
                                "csv"]
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removed tableTools positioning... and it is working now.

Comment: Do you have any details on what you changed it to?